# Custom Listview is not showing up the string

Tags: android

Listview is not showing the string list rather showing only the custom list view text

My string declaration n the main

```
String[] Example = new String[]
        { "Android Introduction","Android Setup/Installation","Android Hello World",
                "Android Layouts/Viewgroups","Android Activity & Lifecycle","Intents in Android",
        "Cz"};
ArrayAdapter<String> ExampleArrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Example);

    ListView ExampleListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ExampleListView.setAdapter(ExampleArrayAdapter);
```

here is my customAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public CustomAdapter (Activity activity, String[] items){
    super(activity, R.layout.custom_layout, items);
    inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
 Random rnd = new Random();

   int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(257), rnd.nextInt(258));

  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return rowView;


}
}
```

here is the custom layout of my app, i have updated its...........
custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:background="@drawable/blue_bg">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="345dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white_bg">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="left" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="Tweet body text here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are using a custom Adapter but not setting the text in `CustomAdapter`. Find the textView in `custom_layout` using `rowView` and then set it's text using `textView.setText(items[position])`

Comment: What are you planning to do? You have two TextViews and an ImageView but you are just passing a String to the custom Adapter. Nevertheless, you should set `item` String to any of the `TextView`, then you'll see some output.

Comment: some example will be helpful sir

Comment: Make your `items` global. Then in your `getView`, before `return rowView`, find the `textView` using `textView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` then set the text using `textView.setText(items[position]);`.

Comment: it's not working sir..it stopped working

Comment: What's the error? Please post logcat.

Comment: I will update the post within few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your CustomAdapter object in Activity As:

```
CustomAdapter ExampleArrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Example);

    ListView ExampleListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ExampleListView.setAdapter(ExampleArrayAdapter);
```

And Your Adapter Code should be:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String[] items;
public CustomAdapter (Activity activity, String[] items){
          super(activity, 0, items);
    inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
 Random rnd = new Random();

   int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(257), rnd.nextInt(258));

  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
    rowView.setBackgroundColor(color);
TextView tv = (TextView) rowView .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(items[position]);
    return rowView;


}
}
```

Comment: "There is no default constructor available" in the adapter code and what is tv?

Comment: can you post custom_layout?

Comment: "unfortunately example has stopped" ...sorry to bug you so much miss

Answer (score 3):

> Listview is not showing the string list rather showing only the custom
>   list view text

Becuase you are not setting  text for `TextView` in each row of ListView just setting color of row.

so customize `getView` method and set TextView text from `items` String Array. see following example for more help:
[Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)